# Finding the integral of $\int_{e}^{n \pi} \frac{\sin x}{x \log x}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I have a question where I am supposed to show that the following sequence of numbers converges:

$$a_n = \int_{e}^{n \pi} \frac{\sin x}{x \log x} \mathrm dx$$

To show this, should I am supposed to show that the sequence is Cauchy or should compute the integral. But eventually, I need to calculate the integral. Any hints on how to go about it?

Comment: Hint: rewrite you sequence $a_n$ as partial sum of some series and apply [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) to that series.

Comment: I will try that, thanks for hint.

Answer (score 0):

For sufficient $N\in \mathbb{N}$, if $n,m >N$, then you can verify that

$$\big|\int_{e}^{n\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x\log{x}}dx- \int_{e}^{m\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x\log{x}}dx\big|
\leq \big|\int_{e}^{n\pi}\frac{1}{x\log{x}}dx- \int_{e}^{m\pi}\frac{1}{x\log{x}}dx\big|$$

and you can integrate the right side using a simple $u$-substitution.

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't work as eventually, we get $|\log(\log(\frac{n}{m}))|$ and it isn't bounded by $\epsilon$?